# Limiting threads without Semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have a program in which I uses a SemaphoreSlim to regulate the number of threads running a particular section of code. I do this to make sure I do not overwhelm the system. I was wondering if there was any other way to do this without the semaphore. I've looked into the ThreadPool and i'm not sure that is quite it. Here is an example of what I'm doing.

```
        semaphore.Wait();

        if (Options.MaxMessagesPerSecond.HasValue)
        {
            Throttle();
        }

        if (Options.ConcurrentDispatch)
        {          
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Send, args);       
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            Extensions.RaiseEvent(Send, this, args);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
```

There is code that handles the release else where to cover the return. I am really wondering if there is another way to get he effect of limiting the number of threads running without using a semaphore.

Comment: You should stick with semaphores. This is the sort of thing they were designed to do. Anything else you come up with will just be another version of a semaphore.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not want to use semaphores?

Comment: Was just looking into different way of accomplishing the same thing

Comment: Both the threadpool and a semaphore are reasonable solutions.  Do note the whopper bug in your snippet, you never call Release() when Options.ConcurrentDispatch is *true*.  If you want to throttle correctly then the Release() call should be made by the worker thread, just before it terminates.   All and all good reasons to leave it up to the threadpool :)